# Convert String to array 2 D in java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have this String is a result from query 
07:40,09:00,10:20,11:40,|08:00,09:00,|

1) i want to eliminate the last ,|

2) convert it to

```
String[][] matrix ={
    {"07:40","08:00"},
    {"09:00","09:00"},
    {"10:20",null},
    {"11:40",null}
};
```

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: Is that fixed format i.e. columns seperated by pipe i.e. "|"?

Comment: no is a variable Strin from a result of Query, yes i separat the column by pipe

Comment: Will it always be 6 variables? Does order matter? Will the pipeline characters be fixed? There isn't enough info here to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi try this solution it works and not only in a perfect way but it take care of null strings ans malformed strings enjoy

```
             public static String[][] getModel(String answer){
     try {
         System.out.println(answer);
             if(answer.contains("|")){
                            String[] cols=answer.split(",\\|");

                            System.out.println("case found");
                            System.out.println("size 1:"+cols.length);

                            int dimensionCol=cols.length;
                            int dimensionRow=cols[0].split(",").length;

                            System.out.println(dimensionCol+" "+dimensionRow);
                            String[][] result=new String[dimensionRow][dimensionCol];

                            int i=0,j=0;
                            for(String colElement:cols){
                                i=0;
                                String[] datas = colElement.split(",");
                                for (String data : datas) {
                                    result[i][j]=(!data.equals(""))?data:null;
                                    System.out.print(result[i][j]);
                                    i++;
                                }
                                System.out.println("");
                                j++;
                                         }
                            return result;
                           }else{


                                  System.out.println("empty String return by null");
                                  return null;


                           }
          }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
     return null;
   }
```

here is the main test methode

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {


   // String model = "07:40,09:00,10:20,11:40,|08:00,09:00,|";
    String model = "";
    String[][] model1 = getModel(model);
          if (model1!=null) {
        for (String[] model11 : model1) {
              for (String model111 : model11) {
                  System.out.print(model111+" ");
              }
              System.out.println("");

    }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would:

1) elimitate the last ",|" using e.g. `substring()`

2) split the string with `string.split("|")`, and keep the length as `numTimes`

3) cycle over the split result and split each substring by `substr.split(",")`

4) keep the maximum length of the length of the splits in an int called `len`

5) create the result array `String[][] matrix = new String[len][numTimes]`

5) create a for loop `for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){...`

6) within the loop add the correct values into `matrix` (check for null)

Comment: Upvoted for explaining the necessary steps of the process so succinctly

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C++ then you can try this :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

vector<string>split(string str,string Separator)
{
    vector<string>answer;string temp;
    int len=str.size();
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        bool isSeparator=false;
        for(int j=0;j<Separator.length();j++)
          if(str[i]==Separator[j])
            isSeparator=true;
        if(!isSeparator)
        {
            temp+=str[i];continue;
        }
        if(temp!="")
          answer.push_back(temp);temp="";
    }
    if(temp!="")
      answer.push_back(temp);
    return answer;
}
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    string str="07:40,09:00,10:20,11:40,|08:00,09:00,|";
    vector<string>v=split(str,"|"); // First split with respect to '|'
    vector<string>matrix[100]; // Maximum row of time
    for(i=0;i<v.size();i++)
    {
        vector<string>temp;
        temp=split(v[i],","); // Now split with respect to ','
        for(j=0;j<temp.size();j++)
        {
            matrix[j].push_back(temp[j]);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;;i++)
    {
        if(matrix[i].size()==0) // Break the loop, because no time will be on below
          break;
        for(j=0;j<matrix[i].size();j++)
          cout<<matrix[i][j]<<" ";
        cout<<"\n";
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but OP needs answer for java.

Comment: @almasshaikh it was not stated at first :(

Comment: tanks but i m using java

Comment: @AliAkber I know and i did asked OP to add. Really appreciate you helping OP.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String ars[]) {
String string = "11:40,|08:00,09:00,|";
String[] str1 = string.split("\\|");
if (str1.length != 2) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("I dont see a seperator | in your String");
}
String[] rows = str1[0].split(",");
String[] cols = str1[1].split(",");
int maxLength = rows.length > cols.length ? rows.length : cols.length;
String matrix[][] = new String[maxLength][2];

for (int row=0; row<rows.length; row++) {
  matrix[row][0] = rows[row];
}
for (int col=0; col<cols.length; col++) {
  matrix[col][1] = cols[col];
}

for (int i=0; i<maxLength; i++) {
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matrix[i]));
}
}
```

Comment: I don't think writing all of OP's code out is a good way for OP to learn :/

Comment: No i agree with you @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc. But am hoping he is going to get familiar with API's in JAVA and learn them so next time he is going to use those.

Comment: but if i have String string = "11:40,|08:00,09:00,|08:00,09:00";
it should be dynamic

Comment: @almasshaikh help me plz